# Google Cloud Storage NodeJS getFilesStream Async

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Function that never returns; it just hits the timeout limit as a Google Function. It works fine locally within under 60 seconds. Not sure what the issue might be. Code is below:

```js
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
exports.main = async (req, res) => {
  const storage = new Storage({projectId: 'our-project'});
  const store = storage.bucket('our-bucket');
    const incomplete = {
    LT04: [],
    LT05: [],
    LE07: [],
    LC08: []
  };

  store.getFilesStream({prefix : 'prefixToMatch', autoPaginate : true })
    .on('error', (err) => {
      return console.error(err.toString())
    })
    .on('data', (file) => {
      // Find small/bad files
      if (file.metadata.size === 162) {
        const split = file.name.split('/');
        const prefix = split[2].substr(0, 4);
        incomplete[prefix].push(file.name);
      }
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      return JSON.stringify(incomplete, false, '  ');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code it seems ok. But you need to take into account some additional details about this.

Does your Cloud function's memory is enough for this? I think that you could increase the [memory allocated](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-nodejs#create_a_function) of your CF.

Are you sure that this is due to a timeout issue? If you have not seen the logs you can do it going to the [Error reporting section.](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/viewing-errors)

In case that you have already confirm this, another option could be to change the [timeout duration.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was that I needed to send a "res.send" instead a Promise.resolve. As well, I needed to remove the async before the function.

Thanks for the quick response with guidelines, error was easier than that apparently.